# Git Causing Double Commit of Same Changes

Tags: git, visual-studio

Using git console or visual studio UI shows this same problem. I am describing how it looks when noticed in the visual studio UI, but if I do git status and such from the console the same problem is there. Somehow my git repository is corrupted? Any thoughts on how to uncorrupt?

........

Our team is using the Git in Visual Studio for a project over the last several months. We use the merge workflow. This past month, we have been running into an issue where the result is:

(After I change File X, I commit the changes, but then:)

**[My Visual Studio Team Explorer]**

Shows File X as changed, lists changes in Diff.. so it looks uncommitted.

**[CoWorker's Visual Studio Team Explorer]**

After they `git pull` my changes through the VS UI, without making any of their own changes at all (this coworker does manual ui tests after major commits) sees File X as changed.. except that the Diff shows my uncommitted changes as his base, and the changes says he is undoing my uncommitted changes. When he runs Undo Changes.. it does not fail, but the file changes do not go away, they stay in the Team Explorer window

**[Second CoWorker's Visual Studio Team Explorer]**

Shows same as me, that they are making the changes that mine said I am making (and not undoing like the first coworker's

.. I am at a loss for what to do.

Some random things that might be helpful:

- At some point.. I wanted to run git commands in the command line..
  but it said I didn't have git (even though I was using it in Visual
  Studio), so I downloaded git for windows from the git website.
- This particular File X has this issue over and over and over. Other
  files.. I'm not sure if they do.
- This particular File X does not jump up to the staged commit section 
  when I click the "+" in team explorer to push all changed files into 
  staged. I have to manually right click and stage it.
- When alot of files are changed and not staged, I add a commit message
  and commit, all files get committed except this file. I have to then 
  commit it separately after (or remember to pull all files into staged with
  the "+" and then stage File X manually, and then commit.)
- I believe I also once did a --mixed reset on a commit that had already been pushed to the server. I may have recommited the changes, instead of just pulling them back from the server. Tho... I may have done this because the commit didn't include File X (as I committed without staging first like in one of my previous bullet points), so this may have been done after the issue already existed.

Please help. I'm very sure that I messed something up, and its not a git bug, but have no idea how to go about fixing this

**MORE INFO**:
I updated File X today, and committed the file with another file. Because I did not stage first, it was left behind as an uncommitted file. But looking at the commit I submitted, the files changes are also in the commit that I submitted.. If I commit again, then when looking at diffs between commits, it shows the same diff for this file in both commits (that it didn't have line X that I added and then it did, in both commits)

**MORE INFO**:
Merging two branches today, and File X is listed twice for list of files that have merge conflicts

Comment: Honestly? The VS git interface is terrible and you should use something better as a step 1.

Comment: I'm curious, what about the VS git interface is terrible? Personally, I'm just annoyed that I have to jump to different "tabs/pages" in the team explorer to look at branches and do pulls and such, but the merge conflicts interface is really easy to use. I've only ever used git in VS and in the command line.

Comment: If the tool you're using doesn't show a comprehensive, visual graph of the commits, it is utterly useless in my opinion

Comment: Can you send me a link of what you mean by a comprehensive visual graph of the commits?

Comment: I would recommend getting a better understanding of what git is and does.

Comment: Is there something in git in particular that stands out as me not understanding?

Comment: I ask about the comprehensive visual graphic because VS does have a somewhat graphic in their "View History" for a branch

Comment: Yeah, forget the current vs git interface. Except maybe for commiting, it can cause strange behaviors, like it don't see changes, or see unexisting one. Or if you jump big diffs between branches, with thousand of files, it acn cause some file access errors(i think it's trying to diff, or load your project files, but with half of the files missing).

Comment: Really unpredictable. So, basically the command line is the single point of truth, but there are good gius out there. Tortoise is a good one, VS code has a very nice one too. Gitkraken can visualize everything(google some images).

Comment: But if you use any 3rd party tool, test them, some of them can behave strangely, like auto converting branch names to start with a capital letter, or commit with linux ending despite of your settings, what can cause problems down the line.

Comment: I prefer GitExtensions as my git interface